# Microsoft Dynamics CRM display error returned from plugin through javascript

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2013

I am using Microsoft Dynamics CRM (off premise)

Microsoft Dynamics® CRM Online Spring '14 (6.1.0.575)

Via the javascript SDK making a call to create an entity which fires off a plugin. We do our custom validations in the plugin in pre-validation.

Javascript create call example from here -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334427.aspx

```
//Create the Account
SDK.REST.createRecord(
  account,
  "Account",
  function (account) {
    writeMessage("The account named \"" + account.Name + "\" was created with the AccountId : \"" + account.AccountId + "\".");
    writeMessage("Retrieving account with the AccountId: \"" + account.AccountId + "\".");
    retrieveAccount(account.AccountId)
  },
  errorHandler
);
```

And then I can handle the error using that errorHandler function, like this:

```
function errorHandler(error) {
   writeMessage(error.message);
}
```

However, I am trying to get the error to display in the CRM error dialog box from InvalidPluginExecutionException. It displays it when I create the entity from a form, but when I make the call through javascript I can't seem to get it to display in the CRM error dialog box. I want to keep with the CRM theme, not use alert() in javascript, and have users be able to download the full exception that we are sending back.

Is it possible to call the dlg_error.aspx page in CRM and populate it with our error message? I am grasping at straws right now, anything would help out a lot. Thanks!

Comment: Can't you use custom workflow or plugin to create entity record rather than using JavaScript!

Comment: The javascript triggers our plugin, the same would have to be done with a workflow. So plugins are fired by an action to an entity like a create, update, or delete. Here is how a workflow can be triggered http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb955335.aspx There might be a way to fire off a workflow, but it would still need to be through javascript, as far as I know, thanks for your reply!

Comment: No, you don't need JavaScript to fire a Workflow. Create a 'Run on-demand' Workflow. In the ribbon you will have an option to run workflow. I don't know on what action you are running Javascript (On load, On Save, On Change or Ribbon button click). Can you please explain so that I can understand batter what you are trying to achieve. Regards

Comment: That might work I will give it a try. The end goal is to have my plugin display an exception in a CRM error dialog box with the download button for the trace file. I am firing my plugin off with a creation on an entity and I am currently creating that entity the javascript. But I will give the workflow idea a try and let you know how that goes. Thanks!

Comment: Worflow won't display the error exactly as plugin throws. You have to go to the process to get the error details.

Comment: Create a Custom workflow (Code activity) to create entity record and run that using a dialog to get the same error. But TBH it is not going to be a great user experience.

Comment: I have similar scenario, but I am able to run workflow through JS. However I am unable to get workflow exception message in JS. I should be able to get it as Scorpion mentioned from process, but how do I get the process details through SOAP request. Any example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using CRM 2013, I would suggest you to use Workflow instead of JavaScript to create record.

1. Create a new workflow and un-tick the checkbox "Run this workflow in backgroung (recommended)".

[image]

2. Create record from newly created workflow.
3. Save and publish the record.
4. Now go the the ribbon and select 'Run Workflow'.
5. Select the newly created workflow and click 'Add'.
6. If there is an error thrown by Plugin, It will be displayed in standard CRM Error dialog box which will allow you to download the log file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to execute a synchronous jQuery ajax method, without catching error and see what happens. Creating a record from jScript you are using RESTful endpoint of CRM service, I am not sure if the error is going to be promoted in the same way. Try to use Fiddler if you would like to try opening error dialog yourself. Using new synchronous workflow feature might also do the trick.